# Install xampp package in cloud9-ide

Tags: xampp, cloud9-ide

Can we install ***xampp*** package in ***cloud9-ide*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud9 workspaces use Ubuntu Linux to run so you cannot install XAMPP but you can use/install a LAMP stack.

If you [create a workspace](https://c9.io/new) and select the PHP template, you'll have a LAMP stack already setup for you.